# generate hibernate query from java pojo class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, crud

I want to make hibernate query from pojo class, but pojo class uses `mappedBy`. I don't know how can I make proper query.

Already I have tried many ideas, like `ts.clientAccount.clientAccountMapping.id` but it gives error. `clientAccountMapping` is mapped in `clientAccount` pojo

**first class**

```
public class Transaction{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ClientAccount clientAccount;    
}
```

**second class**

```
public class ClientAccount{
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clientAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ClientAccountMapping> clientAccountMapping;
}
```

**third class**

```
public class ClientAccountMapping{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
}
```

Always my compiler gives the following exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [transactio0_.idtransactio0_.clientAccount_accountIdclientAccount.clientAccountMapping]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use join here. like : `From ClientAccount c join c.clientAccountMapping`

Reference : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: thanks, it is working. Transaction ts JOIN  ts.clientAccount.clientAccountMapping mapping WHERE mapping.id

Comment: give a thumbs up!!